# What's the difference of redirect an output using ">", "&>", ">&" and "2&>"?

Tags: linux, shell, unix, scripting

What's the difference of redirect an output using `>`, `&>`, `>&` and `2&>`?

Comment: http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-3.html

Answer (score 57, accepted):

- `>` redirects **stdout** to a file
- `2>&` redirects file handle "2" (almost always **stderr**) to some other file handle (it's generally written as `2>&1`, which redirects stderr to the same place as stdout).
- `&>` and `>&` redirect both **stdout** and **stderr** to a file. It's normally written as `&>file` (or `>&file`). It's functionally the same as `>file 2>&1`.
- `2>` redirects output to file handle 2 (usually **stderr**) to a file.

Comment: More details here: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html and http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/ioredirintro.html

Comment: Does the ampersand signify a file handle, or what does & mean exactly?

Comment: @Banjer: The ampersand usually indicates that the redirection will apply to more than 1 file handle, but the exact semantics depend on the usage of it.

Comment: I prefer > to redirect stdout and 2> for standard error and avoid the &

Comment: `&>` and `>&` are quite different but your answer makes it seem like they are the same.

Comment: @M.M: What is the difference?

Comment: @mipadi [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24793069/).  In brief,  `>&` has a right-hand argument of a file *descriptor*, and an optional left-hand descriptor. Whereas `&>` has a right-hand file *name* and no optional left-hand. (Both operators can have a command as the left hand).  Your claim "`2&>` redirects file handle 2[...]" is wrong, in that usage the 2 is syntactically part of the command

Comment: Try `echo foo 2&>bar; cat bar`

Comment: @lecodesportif, please don't link the ABS. The #bash IRC channel built an entire competing resource -- the [Wooledge BashGuide](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide) -- after getting fed up with the time spent trying to get people to unlearn bad practices they picked up from the ABS's examples.

Answer (score 1):

1> (or >) is for stdout, the output of a command.
2> is for stderr, the error output of the command.

[This page](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html) is a bit wordy, but has good explanations and examples of the different command combinations.