# Why does redirect with &> change the exit code in zsh?

Tags: bash, zsh

I was debugging a shell script, and the problem was that the following code

```
if curl doesntexist -i &> /dev/null;
then
        echo True 
else
        echo False
fi
```

Is, if running zsh, not equivalent to:

```
if curl 6 -i 1> /dev/null 2> /dev/null;
then
        echo True 
else
        echo False
fi
```

The later echos True as expected, but if I redirect with &>, the output is false.
I do not understand this behaviour, for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24793069/what-does-do-in-bash) it says that

> &>name is like 1>name 2>name

Can someone explain why the two snippets do not behave the same if running in zsh? From zsh [docu](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Redirection.html) it says that it should also redirect stdout and stderr, sounds like it should do the same as in bash:

> &> Redirects both standard output and standard error (file descriptor 2) in the manner of ‘> word’

Comment: cannot reproduce, works as expected - both give False

Comment: Are you sure you run in `bash`? The `&>` does not work in other shells in the same way.

Comment: yeah just noticed. Its because I was running zsh

Comment: Cannot replicate, both give `False` **as expected** on `zsh 5.7.1`

Comment: How do you run the script? I do `./test.sh` in my zsh shell, and I get True for one of the scripts and False for the other.

Comment: Okay I see running with `zsh test.sh` works, in zsh running with `./test.sh` breaks, but in bash I can run it with `./test.sh`

Comment: Does `test.sh` have a shebang (`#!/bin/zsh` or similar)? If not, `./test.sh` will be executed with `bash` when run from `bash`, but with `/bin/sh` when run from `zsh`.

Comment: `&>` is not a recognized redirection operator in `/bin/sh`; it's probably being parsed as two separate commands: `curl` run in the background with `&` (which always has 0 as its exit status; the exit status of `curl` itself isn't relevant), and an empty command `> /dev/null` which also always has an exit status of 0: hence the `True` path being taken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect your script does not have a shebang to indicate which shell should be used to execute it, that you have made it executable, and are executing it with something like `./test.sh`. If that is the case, adding something like `#!/bin/bash` or `#!/bin/zsh` will solve the problem.

---

Without a shebang, what actually executes your script depends on which shell you are executing it *from*. `bash` will execute the script with `bash`. `zsh`, however, will execute the script with `/bin/sh`.

In `bash`, `&>` is a redirection operator that redirects both standard error and standard input to the same file.

In `/bin/sh`, though, it is not a redirection operator. The command `curl doesntexist -i &> /dev/null` is parsed as two separate commands:

```
curl doesntexist -i &
> /dev/null
```

The first runs `curl` in the background, and immediately returns with a 0 exit status. (The exit status of `curl` itself is never considered.) The second command is a valid empty command that simply opens `> /dev/null` for writing, then exits with a 0 exit status.

As a result, no matter what `curl` might do, the exit status that `if` cares about is just the *last* one in the list, that of `> /dev/null`. Since that is 0, you get the `True` path.

In `bash`, where `&>` is the valid redirection operator, `if` looks at the exit status of `curl` as expected.